# Show woocommerce products in author archive

Tags: author, woocommerce-offtopic, author-template

I've added permissions to authors to add products in woocommerce. I would like to know if there is a way to display products by current user in archives.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to modify author archive queries-

```
function wpd_author_archive( $query ){
    if ( $query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query() ){
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'product' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_author_archive' );
```